# compile error with dirent.h on 64bit windows

Tags: c++, windows, dirent.h

OS: Windows 8 64-bit

Compiler: Visual Studio 2012

Problem Description: When I try to compile codes with "dirent.h" in "x64", error occurs. No matter dirent.h is used or not. The error won't occur if the codes were compile under "win32" setting.

Error MSG: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(146): fatal error C1189: #error :  "No Target Architecture"

EXAMPLE:

```
#include stdio.h  
#include sys/types.h
#include dirent.h   

int main(int argc, char* argv[])  
{  

    const char *name = ".";  
    DIR *dirp;  
    struct dirent *dp;  

    dirp = opendir(name);  
    if (dirp != NULL) {  
        printf("opendir %s succeed!\n", name);    
    }  
    closedir(dirp);  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question being asked: You are missing <> in your includes.

Comment: Do you get the same error on a hello world program?  If so, it is nothing to do with dirent.h.  The windows equivalent is FindFirstFile, FindNext, FindClose as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... Try to go PROJECT-> PROPERTIES -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor, and in Preprocessor Definitions add *AMD64*. It works for me. PS put underscore before and after AMD64.